# Best practices for searchable archive with hadoop with variety of documents(pdf,ppt,MS word,plain text etc.)

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, full-text-search, hdfs, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a problem in which I have a variety of documents in various formats like PDF,MS Word,PPT,plain text etc. which are stored in ***HDFS***. I should extract the contents into elasticsearch index and build a full-text search system for the same.  I've read about the ***ES-Hadoop***. But Am little confused whether I can use ***mapper-attachments plugin*** of ES or ***Apache Tika*** in this case and whether ES-Hadoop is real time or not(in case I use it).

I'm curious that what will be the right way to extract the contents from documents to ES indexes and search the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question about whether using ES mapper attachment plugin or Apache Tika. I would recommend you to use the mapper plugin as it is well integrated with Elasticsearch and will save you a lot of overhead indexing and adding meta information to the documents you are indexing.

As far as I know, ES-Hadoop do not expose streaming (real-time) API's. I am working with ES-Hadoop and Apache Spark and had to implement sort of streaming data to Elasticsearch by myself using Apache Kafka.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can we use an HDFS location(where doc file is stored) as source in mapper attachments plugin ? I don't want to store the file in ES.File should be in HDFS,only textual contents and meta-data to be stored in ES.

Comment: Not that I know off such an option. The mapper attachment plugin DSL requires you to 64-Base encode your files and then add the encoded data as the value to your attachment field type. Here is a [link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments) to the DSL. You can though write your documents meta-data to the attachment plugin and query them later on.